# PostgreSQL Backup Information

Tags: postgresql, backup

How do you get the Backup History for a PostgreSQL database from within the database?

for example:
in SQL Server you look into msdb.dbo.backupset
in Oracle you check v$rman_output

is there a similar way here

Thanks

Comment: Which backup tool to you use? With barman [list-backup](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.11/#list-backup) is probably what you are looking. With pgbackrest you are probably looking for [info](https://pgbackrest.org/command.html#command-info)

Answer (score 0):

A PostgreSQL backup leaves no trace in the database. If you use WAL archiving, you will get a `*.backup` file for each online file system backup in the WAL archive directory, but that's all.

You best use a third-party backup solution like pgBackRest, which will provide such information.